# What is this Haskell Syntax (type level operators?)

Tags: haskell, syntax, type-level-computation

What does `'[]` or `':` signify in Haskell code? Some examples -

[**Example 1:**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/haskell-cafe/2KS4yxtCr2o/OXSddmQPo3MJ)

```
data OrderPacket replies where
  NoOrders :: OrderPacket '[]
```

[**Example 2:**](https://github.com/goldfirere/glambda/blob/master/src/Language/Glambda/Exp.hs#L33)

```
data Elem :: [a] -> a -> * where
  EZ :: Elem (x ': xs) x
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Haskell user guide section on [Promoted list and tuple lists](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/promotion.html):

> With -XDataKinds, Haskell's list and tuple types are natively promoted
>   to kinds, and enjoy the same convenient syntax at the type level,
>   albeit prefixed with a quote:
>
> ```
> data HList :: [*] -> * where
>   HNil  :: HList '[]
>   HCons :: a -> HList t -> HList (a ': t)
>
> data Tuple :: (*,*) -> * where
>   Tuple :: a -> b -> Tuple '(a,b)
>
> foo0 :: HList '[]
> foo0 = HNil
>
> foo1 :: HList '[Int]
> foo1 = HCons (3::Int) HNil
>
> foo2 :: HList [Int, Bool]
> foo2 = ...
> ```
>
> (Note: the declaration for HCons also requires -XTypeOperators because
>   of infix type operator (:').) For type-level lists of two or more
>   elements, such as the signature of foo2 above, the quote may be
>   omitted because the meaning is unambiguous. But for lists of one or
>   zero elements (as in foo0 and foo1), the quote is required, because
>   the types [] and [Int] have existing meanings in Haskell.

So basically it is the same syntax prefixed with a single quote but which operates at kind level. Some playup using `ghci` with the above code:

```
λ> :t HNil
HNil :: HList '[]
λ> :t HCons
HCons :: a -> HList t -> HList (a : t)
λ> let x = 3 `HCons` HNil
λ> :t x
x :: Num a => HList '[a]
λ> let x = Tuple 3 "spj"
λ> :t x
x :: Num a => Tuple '(a, [Char])
```

Comment: perfect (for ghci I needed `:set -XDataKinds -XTypeOperators -XKindSignatures -XGADTs`).